# ExtJS file upload to ASP.net MVC status OK but no content being sent

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, extjs4

I'm trying to upload a file from an ExtJS 4.2 front-end to a C#/ASP.net MVC 2 backend.  My front end code is largely modeled upon that from the ExtJS docs at: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File.  After the file is chosen and the upload button is clicked a request status of 200 ensues and a server side round trip is successfully made, but the server side code indicates that Request.Files["file"] is null.

Using Chrome dev tools it is apparent that a file upload is being attempted but there is no content between the boundaries:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryh2Q8Ya8kWQkiSLOb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="users"; filename="0_USER_INFO.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet


------WebKitFormBoundaryh2Q8Ya8kWQkiSLOb--
```

Below are relevant portions of my client and server side code.  Currently when I click upload I get an ExtJS alert with header of "Failure" and msg of "postedFile == null" (see `case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID`).  What can I do to ensure the file contents actually get sent and that `Request.Files["file"]` on the server side is *not* null?

CLIENT SIDE CODE:

```
Ext.define('Tools.view.users.Manager', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.usermanager',

    title: 'User Manager',
    items: [{
        title: 'Import',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            width: 400,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            //frame: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'filefield',
                name: 'users',
                fieldLabel: 'New Users',
                labelWidth: 75,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                allowBlank: false,
                anchor: '100%',
                buttonText: 'From Excel'
            }],

            buttons: [{
                text: 'Upload',
                handler: function () {
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    if (form.isValid()) {
                        form.submit({
                            url: '/User/Upload',
                            waitMsg: 'Uploading user data...',
                            success: function (form, action) {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
                            },
                            failure: function (form, action) {
                                switch (action.failureType) {
                                    case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                                        break;
                                    case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                                        break;
                                    case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

SERVER SIDE:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files["file"];
        if (postedFile == null)
        {
            return Content("{\"success\": false, \"msg\": \"postedFile == null\"}");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("{\"success\": true, \"msg\": \"postedFile != null\"}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049848/1580743).

> You need to use HttpPostedFileBase in controller action parameters inorder to get the filedata that you have posted.