# Unable to access self.parentViewController.property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have implemented a subclass of ECSlidingViewController.

```
InitialViewController.h
@interface InitialViewController : ECSlidingViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) WebViewController *webVC;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MenuViewController *menuVC;

@end
```

I need access to the .webVC from the .menuVC, but am unable to access them from self.parentViewController.webVC getting the error:

```
 "UIViewController does not have a member named webVC"
```

but when I check in the debugger

```
po self: <MenuViewController>
po self.parentViewController: <InitialViewController>
po self.parentViewController.webVC: error: property 'webVC' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'
```

However, when I navigate the object tree of self in the local variable window, I can go

```
-self <MenuViewController> 0x0000001
  -UITableViewController
    -UIViewController
      -_parentViewController <InitialViewController>
        -webVC <WebViewController
        -menuVC <MenuViewController> 0x0000001
```

Where self and self.parentViewController.menuVC have the same memory address

When I navigate down and right-click->print Description, I get

```
    Printing description of self->_parentViewController->menuVC:
<MenuViewController: 0x8e8c720>
```

Those '->' and the '_' make me think I'm seriously missing something involving pointers and ivars.

I'm also interested if there is a better way to implement this functionality. This kind of smells like I'm breaking MVC with a child Controller knowing about itself and its parent. However, selections on the menu directly manipulate the webView I have loaded.

Comment: See [this post][1] about HttpPostedFileBase.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475023/request-files-is-empty-in-mvc-file-upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer:

UIViewController does not have this property built in so you need to cast it:

```
[(InitialViewController*)self.parentViewController webVC]
```

---

### Explanation:

This is a question of Classes and SubClasses. Say I have a class `MyView` which is a subclass of UIView. This class has a couple methods on it, `-(void)method1;` and `-(void)method2;`. The .h would look something like this:

```
@interface MyView : UIView

- (void)method1;
- (void)method2;

@end
```

I then create a `MyView*` named `thisView` and assign it to my ViewController's view property:

```
#import "MyView.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MyView* thisView = [[MyView alloc] init];
    [self setView: thisView];
}
```

The UIViewController class's property, `view` is declared like this:

```
@property (...) UIView* view;
```

**Pay extra special attention to the `UIView*` there.**

Because `view` is declared as a UIView*, it will accept values that are subclasses of UIView*, but when I access it later, it will give me a MyView in a box labeled `UIView`.

In other words, consider this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MyView* thisView = [[MyView alloc] init];
    [self setView: thisView];

    UIView* returnedView = thisView; //This is perfectly fine
}
```

UIViewController will return something along the lines of `returnedView`, which is a `MyView` in a `UIView` container.

When your program goes to access the view, all it knows is that has received something in a box labeled "UIView", so it only knows that it can run methods on it that are present in the UIView class. We have to explicitly tell it "No, this is a MyView," and we do that with casting:

```
[self.view method1]; //This will break
[(MyView*)self.view method1]; //This will work
```

#### Back to your problem

When you access `self.parentViewController`, you are given a InitialViewController in a UIViewController box, so you have to explicitly tell your program that it is an InitialViewController. You do that by casting:

```
InitialViewController* parentVC = (InitialViewController*)self.parentViewController;
[parentVC.webVC doSomething];
```

---

### Warning:

Your VC that is accessing webVC must have a declaration of `(InitialViewController*)`, so you'll need to watch out for forward declaration errors.

If you are unfamiliar with this, it is when Class A imports Class B, but Class B also imports Class A:

```
A
--->Import B

B
--->Import A

Which results in

A
--->Import B
------->Import A
----------->Import B
and so on.
```

A class cannot import itself.

Comment: I was just gonna say: casting.

Comment: @NovaJoe Beat you to it haha :)

Comment: Wonderful explanation! I noticed in the self hierarchy that custom classes were wrapped with their parent classes, but couldn't understand why. Thanks a bundle!